# Z3 String/Char xor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, z3, z3py

I'm working with Z3 in Python and am trying to figure out how to do String operations. In general, I've played around with `z3.String` as the object, doing things like `str1 + str2 == 'hello world'`. However, I have been unable to accomplish the following behavior:

```
solver.add(str1[1] ^ str1[2] == 12) # -- or --
solver.add(str1[1] ^ str1[2] == str2[1])
```

So basically add the constraint that character 1 xor character 2 equals 12. My understanding is that the string is defined as a sequence of 8-bit BitVectors under the hood, and BitVectors should be able to be xor'd.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So far I don't expose ways to access characters with a function. You would have to define auxiliary functions and axioms that capture extraction. The operator [] extracts a sub-sequence, which is of length 1 if the index is within bounds.

Here is a way to access the elements:

```
from z3 import *

nth = Function('nth', StringSort(), IntSort(), BitVecSort(8))

k = Int('k')
str1, str2, s = Strings('str1 str2 s')

s = Solver()
s.add(ForAll([str1, k], Implies(And(0 <= k, k < Length(str1)), Unit(nth(str1, k)) == str1[k])))

s.add( ((nth(str1, 1)) ^ (nth(str2, 2))) == 12)
```

Comment: Would it simplify things if I just used an Array like `a = z3.Array('a',z3.IntSort(),z3.BitVecSort(8))` to mimic a string? I've tested that I can just do `a[0] ^ a[1]` and it seems to work, plus it should be easy enough for python itself to concat the array together to form an actual string.

Also, it looks like there's been some work done by researchers on it by z3-str <https://github.com/z3str/Z3-str>. Thoughts on this?