# Z3python XOR sum?

Tags: python, python-3.x, z3, z3py

I'm currently trying to solve some equation with z3python, and I am coming across a situation I could not deal with.

I need to xor certain `BitVecs` with specific non ascii char values, and sum them up to check a checksum.
Here is an example :

```py
pbInput = [BitVec("{}".format(i), 8) for i in range(KEY_LEN)]
password = "\xff\xff\xde\x8e\xae"
solver.add(Xor(pbInput[0], password[0]) + Xor(pbInput[3], password[3]) == 300)
```

It results in a z3 type exception : 
`z3.z3types.Z3Exception: Value cannot be converted into a Z3 Boolean value`.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991948/z3-string-char-xor) and tried to apply a function to my `password` string, adding this line to my script :
`password = Function(password, StringSort(), IntSort(), BitVecSort(8))`
But of course it fails as the string isn't an ASCII string. 
I don't care about it being a string, I tried to just do `Xor(pbInput[x] ^ 0xff)`, but this doesn't work either. I could not find any documentation on this particular situation.

EDIT :
Here is the full traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solve.py", line 18, in <module>
    (Xor(pbInput[0], password[0]) 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/z3/z3.py", line 1555, in Xor
    a = s.cast(a)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/z3/z3.py", line 1310, in cast
    _z3_assert(self.eq(val.sort()), "Value cannot be converted into a Z3 Boolean value")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/z3/z3.py", line 91, in _z3_assert
    raise Z3Exception(msg)
z3.z3types.Z3Exception: Value cannot be converted into a Z3 Boolean value
```

Thanks in advance if you have any idea about how I could do this operation!

Comment: You need to provide the full traceback...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

- `Xor` is for `Bool` values only; for bit-vectors simply use `^`
- Use the function `ord` to convert characters to integers before passing to `xor`

You didn't give your full program (which is always helpful!), but here's how you'd write that section in z3py as a full program:

```py
from z3 import *

solver = Solver()
KEY_LEN = 10

pbInput = [BitVec("c_{}".format(i), 8) for i in range(KEY_LEN)]
password = "\xff\xff\xde\x8e\xae"
solver.add((pbInput[0] ^ ord(password[0])) + (pbInput[3] ^ ord(password[3])) == 300)

print solver.check()
print solver.model()
```

This prints:

```
sat
[c_3 = 0, c_0 = 97]
```

(I gave the variables better names to distinguish more properly.) So, it's telling us the solution is:

```
>>> (0xff ^ 97) + (0x8e ^ 0)
300
```

Which is indeed what you asked for.