# Satisfy K out of N constraints in Z3Py

Tags: z3, z3py

I have a program with logic as described in the pseudocode below. `x` is a string, and `x[k]` will return the decimal charcode of character at index `k`. The `^` operator returns the decimal XOR result of the operands.

```
x = input
int checksum = x[0] ^ x[1] ^ x[2]
int sum = 0

sum += x[36] ^ x[23] == 111
sum += x[23] ^ x[29] == 101
sum += x[29] ^ x[30] == 116
sum += x[30] ^ x[9] == 115
sum += x[9] ^ x[25] == 0

return sum == checksum and x[0] ^ x[29] == 100 and x[1] ^ x[30] == 200
```

I want to find input that makes this program return `true`. If I want to solve this problem in Z3Py, is there a way for me to do it? I need some K out of N constraint that allows me to express the constraints as expressions, but I haven't found support for this.

Psedocode for what I would like to do with Z3:

```
int checksum = x[0] ^ x[1] ^ x[2]

bools = []

bools.append(Bool(x[36] ^ x[23] == 111))
bools.append(Bool(x[23] ^ x[29] == 101))
bools.append(Bool(x[29] ^ x[30] == 116))
bools.append(Bool(x[30] ^ x[9] == 115))
bools.append(Bool(x[9] ^ x[25] == 0))

state.add(bools[0])
state.add(bools[1])
state.add(bools[2])
state.add(bools[3])
state.add(bools[4])
state.add(x[0] ^ x[29] == 100)
state.add(x[1] ^ x[30] == 200)

state.add(PbEq([boolean for boolean in bools], checksum))
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading your problem description, I don't see why you need K-out-of-N constraints for this problem. It seems like a straightforward encoding using bit-vector theory. But perhaps I didn't quite understand the problem you're trying to solve. It'd help to show what you tried, and what failed.

In any case, if you really need K-out-of-N constraints, then Z3 has special support for them in various forms:

- [AtMost](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#a0dac4394936ce99b2fb882e257f86ad7)
- [AtLeast](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#a8575bdeb9d1b8feac119aa162b5acfa6)
- [PbEq](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#a8c87e8baf5a179ce8f48cd266490b2a2)
- [PbLe](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#a8c87e8baf5a179ce8f48cd266490b2a2)
- [PbGe](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#a0d18822e1cda06e2b06590fb3c5dbe18)

Such constraints are known as "Pseudo-boolean," and hence the `Pb` prefix.

Comment: I edited my question.

If you see an easier way of solving this problem, I would like to hear.

Comment: I don't see the need for any N-out-of-K constraint for this problem. It sounds awfully similar to this existing question, take a look and see if the answer there helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57936605/z3python-xor-sum/57937419#57937419

Comment: The question in the link is a vanilla XOR problem. My problem requires you to solve a variable number of constraints, derived from the `checksum`. The `checksum` is in turn derived from the variables in the constraints themselves, going full circle. I might be of course be missing something, but my problem seems different at face value.

Comment: The hint was about how you'd go coding it in Z3py idoms. Stackoverflow works the best if you first try something and ask for help when you get stuck, instead of asking for full solutions. See the MVCE guidelines here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example